# Передать массив в функцию только в том случае, если он существует

Tags: php, массивы

Нужно сравнить несколько массивов на совпадение значений.

```
$result = array_intersect($var_1,$var_2,$var_3,$var_4,$var_5,$var_6,$var_7);
```

Если массив есть,то мы его передаём, если нет, то сравниваем остальные и так для каждого. Если нет `$var_2`, но есть остальные, то сравниваем так `$result = array_intersect($var_1,$var_3,$var_4,$var_5,$var_6,$var_7);`, если нет `$var_5,$var_6`, но есть остальные, то сравниваем так `$result = array_intersect($var_1,$var_2,$var_3,$var_4,$var_7);` И так далее.

Comment: «если нет» – то даже переменная `$var_N` не определена?

Comment: Всегда существует только `$var_1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [`call_user_func_array()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.call-user-func-array.php) – вызывает функцию с массивом параметров.
2. [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-filter.php) фильтрует массив.

План такой: из массива массивов оставляем только непустые элементы, и передаем их в `array_intersect()`:

```
$result = call_user_func_array(
    'array_intersect',
    array_filter(
        array( $var_1,$var_2,$var_3,$var_4,$var_5,$var_6,$var_7 ),
        function($a){ return isset($a)  &&  is_array($a)  &&  !!count($a);}
    )
);
```

[Рабочий пример](http://ideone.com/hWmlwL)

Comment: Спасибо! То, что нужно. Работает!

Answer (score 1):

Соберите все `var_N`, которые необходимо сравнивать, в один массив-список и передайте в `array_intersect` через `call_user_func_array`

```
call_user_func_array('array_intersect', $array_of_var_N);
```

Comment: Многомерный массив? То есть создаю ключ `[0]` и записываю туда массив `var_1`, `[1]` и записываю туда массив `var_2` - так?

Answer (score 1):

Можно поступить следующим образом - сравнить массивы попарно в цикле, предварительно очистив список массива от значений null и пустых массивов:

```
// Функция фильтрации пустых и несуществующих массивов
function not_empty_arr(...$arrs) {
  $results = [];
  foreach($arrs as $arr) {
    if(isset($arr) && !empty($arr)) {
      $results[] = $arr;
    }
  }
  return $results;
}

// Функция получения пересечения элементов массива
function arr_intersect($arrs) {
  $result = $arrs[0];
  foreach($arrs as $arr) {
    $result = array_intersect($result, $arr);
  }
  return $result;
}

$fst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$snd = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
$thd = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
$fth = [];
$result = arr_intersect(
  not_empty_arr(
    null,
    isset($hello) ? $hello : null,
    isset($fst) ? $fst : null,
    isset($fth) ? $fth : null,
    isset($thd) ? $thd : null,
    isset($snd) ? $snd : null
  ));
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
```

Comment: `$arrs` - масссив, в который поместить все 7 массивов, независимо от его существования?

Comment: В данном случае массивы - это $fst, $snd, $thd, $fth, а $arrs заполняется уже внутри функций not_empty_arr() и arr_intersect().